# how to access specific database in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have created database in postgresql and want to connect database use command like use databaseName but its not working.What is the command to access specific date base in postgresql.

in my sql if want connect database we will use command like use databaseName not working in postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation for `psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html):

> `-d dbname`
>
> `--dbname=dbname`
>
> Specifies the name of the database to connect to.

If you are already connected:

```
\c or \connect [ -reuse-previous=on|off ] [ dbname [ username ] [ host ] [ port ] | conninfo ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In shell:

```
psql -d postgres://dbuser:dbpwd@dbhost/databaseName
```

In postgresql repl:

```
\c databaseName
```